# how to return value based on max columns by pandas？

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

**Input**

```
df
   
A   B   C
0   0   0
1   2   4
5   8   7
9   1   1
8   8   8
```

All values≥0

**Goal**

```
A   B   C   D
0   0   0   unk
1   2   4   Z
5   8   7   Y
9   1   1   X
8   8   8   balance
```

Return D column, the detail as follow:

- Return value base on the max value among `A/B/C` columns
- If the max value in `A` , then `D` value is X, `B` is Y, C is Z, and all values must not be the same.
- If all values among `A/B/C` is same, when the same value is 0, then return unk. If the same value is not 0, it returns balance.

**Try**

I search something like `idxmax` or `max(axis=1)` but could not get it, especially the `balance` and `unk`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
key_map={0:'X',1:'Y',2:'Z'}
def mapper(row):
    if row['A']==row['B']==row['C']:
        if row['A']==0:
             return 'unk'
        else:
             return 'balance'
    else:
        column=np.argmax([row['A'],row['B'],row['C']])
        return key_map[column]
df['D']=df.apply(mapper,axis=1)
```

Explanation: Create a dictionary 'key_map'. Using apply(), call mapper() & return values according to the conditions mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Let's try your logic:

```
# extract max and min
max_vals, min_vals = df.max(1), df.min(1)

# extract columns with max values
idxmax = df.idxmax(1)

# map the column names
key_map={'A':'X', 'B':'Y', 'C':'Z'}

df['D'] = np.select((max_vals==0, max_vals==min_vals),
                    ('unk','balance'), idxmax.map(key_map)
                   )
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C        D
0  0  0  0      unk
1  1  2  4        Z
2  5  8  7        Y
3  9  1  1        X
4  8  8  8  balance
```